# Easily modifiable chess engine

Tags: engines, software, programming

I'm looking for a chess engine that I can (relatively) easily go into the source code, make some tweaks, recompile, and run the modified engine. Ideally, the source code would be well documented and easy to read and edit. Playing strength is a secondary priority.

Are any engines known for being easy to read and modify?

Comment: This was precisely the idea of my Secondchess engine: https://github.com/emdio/secondchess

Comment: I’ve been trying to read engine code lately and stumbled upon this engine https://github.com/Tearth/Cosette/tree/master/Cosette docs aren’t great but code is very readable